# How can I make a plot with a scale like this (-1, 13000)

Tags: r, plot, scale, axis

I want a diagram where the scale starts at -1 and goes to 13000.

But if I write this `axis(1, at=seq(0,13000,2000), labels=seq(-1,13000,2000))` then on the x axis the labels will be -1, 1999, 3999 etc.

I want -1, 2000, 4000, 6000 etc

Comment: Try `at=c(-1, seq(0,13000,2000)[-1])`. This combines `-1` with your vector `at` without its first element, `0`. And remove `labels`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can suppress the x axis in your plot, then add a separate axis where your labels will work:

```r
plot(x = 1000 * 0:13 - 1, y = (1:14)^2, xlab = "x", ylab = "y", xaxt = "n")
axis(side = 1, at = c(-1, 1:7 * 2000 - 1000))
```

[image]